# How can i calculate the point a camera is looking at using it's rotation?

Tags: java, kotlin, libgdx, rotation

I have a camera that is observing a 2d plane below.

I know the size of the world below, and the position of the camera in relation to it.

I wish to rotate the camera by `x` degrees, but the camera cannot be rotated directly - i can only tell it to look at a point in space.

So i am looking for a function which translates `x°` of rotation into a `y` co-ordinate, but i'm struggling to find appropriate search terms.

Crayon visualisation aid:
[image]

Specifically, I'm looking for the functional formula - but in case already there's some  implementation in my engine that i'm unaware of, i'm implementing with LibGDX.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question, are you looking for the trigonometry formula for this? Or special library functions?

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear enough, i'm after the mathematical formula.

Comment: I answered anyway, but I believe this would be more suited to a math forum if what you're after is a math formula for a basic trigonometry problem (it's not a programming question here)

Comment: Gotcha, I'll bear that in mind for next time!

Comment: You can do this with trigonometry, but what I did is casting a ray from the center of the camera and use `Intersect` on a plane with that ray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define some components that I assume you know:

- `d` - the distance from the camera to the 2D plane
- `y0` - the position of the projection of the camera on the 2D plane (where the 90deg line hits the plane in your diagram). This is likely 0 in your coordinate system, but let's keep it for completeness.
- `angleFromHorizontal` - the desired angle in degrees as defined in your diagram (between 0 exclusive and 180 exclusive)

The formula for the *y* position is the following:

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.PI
import kotlin.math.tan

val angleFromNormal = 90.0 - angleFromHorizontal
val y = d * tan(angleFromNormal * PI / 180) + y0
```

Actually you don't even need the "reverse" of the angle. You can just invert the tangent:

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.PI
import kotlin.math.tan

val y = d / tan(angleFromHorizontal * PI / 180) + y0
```

Comment: I need to do some fine tuning before i can confirm, but a rough implementation already looks promising. Thank you so much!